# What linux / apache host server settings could be affecting my upload speeds?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, configuration

Upload speeds to one particular server of mine are drastically slower than expected, or tolerable.

I am moving a site to a new host; part of the functionality of the site is the upload of several large (>50Mb) files daily. The current upload speeds are unacceptably slow on the new server.

I am new to linux and apache server configuration; are there any settings which should be changed, or checked / tweaked, to allow for maximum file transfer speeds?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check some things :

- Check the network speed of the server in the network with a benchmark tool like ttcp
- Check if a transfer file of a 50 mb
  file to the server with for example
  sftp or netcat is slow as web
  trasnfer file through apache
- Check if the new Server is slow when
  write to disk
- Check with top how much the
  consuption of CPU increase when the
  transfer file happen

Answer (score 1):

The answer was:  An expired SSL certificate.  Renewing the certificate solved the problems.

thank you all for your help;  i learned a great deal from following your leads.

Answer (score 0):

There's all sorts of possible reasons for slowness...

My best guess: mismatch between server and ethernet switch or bad cable:

Try:

```
ifconfig
```

If the errors, dropped, overruns, frame or carrier on RX or TX are anything other than "0" you could have a problem...

If you see collisions try:

```
ethtool eth0
```

(replace eth0 with whatever the network card being used to copy the data in question is)

If it's showing up as half duplex or simply doesn't match what the switch is showing for that port, that could easily be your problem.

Is it possible that you just have a slow server?  Very slow hard drive?  Very slow CPU?  Very slow memory?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a "wget ftp://ftp.xs4all.nl/pub/test/100mb.bin" on the server or just try to download another big file. Is that file downloading fast? Then the problem can be a number of things: maybe the bottleneck is the DSL connection you're uploading with, or apache is set up with an upload cap. 
Some hosting providers host different VPS's on a server with slow sata hard-disks, write-speeds are extremely slow then.